# Cannot change brightness of in-built laptop screen [Windows 11]

Tags: windows, display, windows-11

Just bought a new Medion Erazer Major X20 which came with Windows 11 Home.

The screen is too bright. Under `Settings > System > Display > Brightness` there is a slider showing the nominal screen brightness. But moving the slider up and down changes nothing. The screen is exactly the same brightness on 0% and 100%.

Same thing using the in-built function keys. On this laptop this is `FN+F11` (lower) and `FN+F12` (higher).

What prevents the screen brightness from changing?

Comment: Update the Video and Power drivers and consider updating BIOS if the vendor has a decent BIOS update routine.

Comment: @John: Thanks, that is good advice but I've found the issue and updated the question with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, appear to have found the issue. This is a brand new laptop, so I am still in the process of setting it up (installing new applications, uninstalling bloatware, stopping services, and so on).

I recalled setting some display-related services to `Manual`. After carefully reviewing the list and checking each one that looked vaguely relevant, found `NVIDIA Display Container LS`. This was originally set to `Automatic`. After starting that service, the screen is now changing brightness.

Have now changed the service back from `Manual` to `Automatic`.

Hope this proves useful to someone else.